# Installing apps from Android Market or alternatives to a virtual Android x86 device

Tags: google-play-store

I'm using Oracle Virtual Box to emulate an Android-x86 device. I installed android-x86-2.2-r2-sparta.iso to a virtual HD.

Are there any way to install apk packages from Android Market (http://market.android.com) or do I have to download them only from "unnoficial ways"? Any suggestions for the 2nd case?

PS: Note that I'm asking for a solution for that particular case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not familiar with that particular distribution.  However, in general unless the build you installed contains the "Google Experience" apps (or if there is a separate Market package for it,) you will not be able to use the official Android Market [front-end](https://market.android.com/) to send apps to your virtual device.

There are some alternate markets, such as [Amazon Appstore](http://www.amazon.com/gp/feature.html?ie=UTF8&ref=mas_gs&docId=1000626391), [GetJar](http://www.getjar.com), [SlideMe](http://slideme.org/), etc.  Most will require you to download and install their own Market app in order to get other apps.

If you already have APKs of the apps, you should be able to side-load them either via ADB shell (from [Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)), or via the bundled package installer by executing the APK from the storage area with some sort of a file system browser (if included with the build.)

Comment: Hey, man, I'm new on Android things, so could you explain for me what is Android Maket made for? Only to download the apps and to stay updated? If I download them from anothet device that allows Android Market, can I copy that APKs to mine virtual one?

Comment: 1) Android Market app and web site allow you to download apps from Google's official app "store", and keep them updated.  2) You can retrieve apps from another Android Market enabled device only if it's rooted, since access to internal device storage is restricted.

Comment: Hmm... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29 Nice!

Answer (score 2):

You can only get Google Play apps on officially supported devices, which have the Google Play infrastructure pre-loaded.

If you have an emulator, an overview of how to do this:

1. Install a "pirate" copy of the Google apps from goo.im
2. Modify your build.prop so that you have a "supported" device linked to your account (app developers will choose devices to officially support, so this may be per-app)

Answer (score 2):

I do apologize if I misunderstood your question, but if you just want to be able to install apps from the play store, you could use a free online service called [Evozi](http://apps.evozi.com/apk-downloader/). It lets you download apks directly from the play store. You can install the app by opening the app package in your emulator. Keep in mind however, that you would have to update the apps manually using this method. The only way to let apps auto update is by using a market app installed on your emulator.